# Conversion of simulation time

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am running a simulation (time length: 100seconds) and the results are exported to csv containing two columns. The first one is "Time" in seconds. It contains decimal numbers. The simulation step is variable. I need to convert the decimal numbers to hh:mm:ss format.

Changing the cells' format from Number to Time in Excel is not the solution,as the simulation step is lost.

```
0              00:00:00
0,02           00:28:48 WRONG
0,04           00:57:36 WRONG
0,066          01:35:02 WRONG
0,0998         02:23:43 WRONG
0,14374        03:26:59 WRONG
0,200862       04:49:14 WRONG
0,2751206      06:36:10 WRONG
0,37165678     08:55:11 WRONG
0,497153814    11:55:54 WRONG
```

I expect the format `HH:MM:SS` to keep the step between two simulation instants

```
0              00:00:00
0,02           00:00:00 
0,04           00:00:00
........
1,007964       00:00:01
1,090020       00:00:01
......
100            00:01:40
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] your *expected* result into the post?  Or, at the very least, details of **how** the output you are getting is wrong?  You may want to read the guidelines on how to write a [mcve]

Comment: Yes, if your first column is time, what units are you using - hours, minutes or seconds? Or something else?

Comment: Seconds. I edited my question

Comment: Shouldn't be `0,02` = `00:00:02` if you are working in seconds ?

Comment: @Mikku Or 28 minutes, 48 seconds if you are working in Days, like Excel does

Comment: @DinoC .. Use the formula in the Answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel stores Date/Times as a Double - the Integer portion is the number of Days since 1899-12-31 - so `1` becomes `1900-01-01`, and `60` becomes `1900-02-29`, et cetera.  The Decimal portion is the Time, as a **fraction of a whole day** - `0.5` is **12 noon**.

As such, a value of `0.1` is `2 hours, 24 minutes`, and **not** `100 milliseconds`

This means that your code is giving exactly the right Output for what you have written, but not for what you *wanted* to write.

What you **actually** seem to want is the `TIME` function - which accepts Hours, Minutes and Seconds, and outputs a Time value like so:

```
=TIME(01, 23, 45)
    1:23 AM

=TEXT(TIME(01, 23, 45), "hh:mm:ss")
    01:23:45
```

The `DATE` and `TIME` functions also "overflow".  That is to say, `=TIME(0, 0, 65)` is the same as writing `=TIME(0, 1, 5)`, both give `1 minute, 5 seconds`.

They also "*under*flow", so `TIME(0, 2, -55)` will give `1 minute, 5 seconds` as well (and `=DATE(1900,3,0)` is `1900-02-29` while `=DATE(1901,3,0)` is `1901-02-28`)

Comment: for some reason the output =TEXT(TIME(1;10;50);"hh:mm:ss") is hh:10:50. What am I missing?

Comment: @DinoC What language settings are you using?  `hh` might not be your Hour code.  You could just remove the `TEXT` bit and Format the Cell as Time instead

Comment: thanks Chronocidal. i just remember that I m living in Sweden and hour is called "tid". Instead of hh:mm:ss, I used tt:mm:ss, ;-)

Answer (score 0):

**Use the Formula:**

`=TIME(0,0,SUBSTITUTE(E12,",","."))`

if the format is using , instead of . use function. `=TIME(0,0,E12)`

Change the cell reference accordingly.

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: 2 Minor quibbles here - some countries use `,` as the Decimal Separator, instead of `.` - I suspect that OP's settings are using that format, so your `SUBSTITUTE` would actually break it.  And, your code would display `0,02` as `00:00:02` when OP has specified that it should show `00:00:00` until `1.0`

Comment: =TIME(0;0;E12) gives 12:00 AM, where E12=0,02.

Comment: @DinoC .. You need to also change the Format of that Cell to `Time`